# How to automatically resize the table inside a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've an application I'm working on that places a dataset into a datagridview on the mainform. When the datatable shows up on the datagridview there is a bunch of remaining grey space on teh view, and it has to be manually dragged to resize it in order to fill the entire view. Is there a way I can force it to fill the entire view as it is rendered on the form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the individual column properties. Set the AutoSizeMode property to "Fill" (for one or all, depending on the effect you are looking to achieve), and then use the FillWeight property accordingly to grant specific columns more importance/space.